# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sso_session') for AWS S3 JS SDK

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am executing the following code but getting error

```
//preparing upload parameters
    const params = {
      Bucket: `${config.s3bucket}`,
      Key: `${objectDirectory}/${objectKey}`,
    };

    //geenerating signed url, valid only for 15 minutes
    const command = new PutObjectCommand(params);
    const signedUrl = await getSignedUrl(s3Client, command, {
      expiresIn: 900,
    });
```

Code 2

```
const bucketParams = {
      Bucket: config.s3bucket,
      Key: `Profiles/${result.profilePicture}`,
    };
    const command = new GetObjectCommand(bucketParams);
    const urls = await getSignedUrl(s3Client, command, {
      expiresIn: 60 * 60 * 168,
    });
```

Error Message:

```
{
    "message": "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sso_session')"
}
```

the error occurs whenever I am executing `getSignedUrl`

Comment: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/4183

Comment: How can i fix it...please help

Answer (score 0):

Same is happening to me, rolling back @aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner to 3.208.0 as said in https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/4183 didn't work

Comment: yes..rolling back @aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner to 3.208.0 didn't work.
dont know whats the solution

Comment: @imkumawat solution here https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/4183

Comment: check latest solution
 https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/discussions/4185
working now

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using 2 stacks and trying to call properties from stack1 in stack2:

Try making it a "publicly readonly" in the 1st stack and in the 2nd stack create an interface to hold the signedURL information.

```
export interface <custom_name1> extends cdk.StackProps {
  signed_url: s3.getSignedUrl
}

constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: <custom_name1>) {
  get_signed_url = props.signed_url
}
```